# Would like a dialog window to open once IconFont is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, icons, action

I am working with React and am very new to it. I have a page that has a bunch of FontIcons. I would like the user to click on an icon and have a dialog pop up. I found information on the dialog piece, http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog. I have not found anything on how to make the onclick action render the dialog component.

I know I need to add something in here..

```
<a style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, right: 0, cursor: 'pointer'}} onTouchTap={() => manageBookmark(parsedParams, this.props.documentRdxDoc.acm, this.props.documentRdxDoc.docTitle)}>
<Tooltip label='Manage Bookmark' position='right'>
<FontIcon className='material-icons' style={{color: 
 appConfig.globalFontColor}} tooltip="Notifications">star</FontIcon>
</Tooltip>
</a>
```

Comment: Did the answer below work? It would be good if you could provide feedback on it.

Comment: Oh my bad. Yes it did but the React I am using did not recognize handleOpen = () => { so I had to make it handleOpen() and bind the state when I want to call the it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the dialog component itself and then show it when the FontIcon is clicked (using the `onClick` property).

The dialog state can be tracked using the component state object and modified via handler methods.

Here's an example based on the documentation site:

```
export default class DialogButtonSample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
  };

  render() {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onClick={this.handleClose}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        disabled={true}
        onClick={this.handleClose}
      />,
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            <a style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, right: 0, cursor: 'pointer'}} onTouchTap={() => manageBookmark(parsedParams, this.props.documentRdxDoc.acm, this.props.documentRdxDoc.docTitle)}>
                <Tooltip label='Manage Bookmark' position='right'>
                    <FontIcon className='material-icons' style={{color: appConfig.globalFontColor}} tooltip="Notifications" onClick={this.handleOpen}>star</FontIcon>
                </Tooltip>
                <Dialog
                  title="Dialog With Actions"
                  actions={actions}
                  modal={false}
                  open={this.state.open}
                  onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                >
            </a>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```